# Angular ui sortable: can't drag correctly in nested items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

Hi I've implemented nested sortable items setup in `surveys module` in my project. i.e. I can sort Individual questions AND I can create an empty group, drop a single question into it and like this I fill up the group and I can sort the groups in hierarchy as well. Like this:

[Surveys Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw37H.png)

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!-- Group type questions: -->
<div class="row connector group-type-question-min-height-compulsory myHandle" ng-if="question.type == allQuestionTypes.group" ui-sortable="sortableOptionsGroup" ng-model="question.questions">
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 question-overview">
      <div class="ellipsis">
         <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
         <input type="checkbox" ng-value="0" ng-model="question._selected" />
         <span ng-attr-title="{{question.name}}" ng-if="question.type == allQuestionTypes.group">
         <b>{{question.name}}</b>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 answer-overview pull-right word-wrap">
      <span class="badge">{{showQuestionTypeText(question.type)}}</span>
      <button type="button" ng-if="question.type != allQuestionTypes.group" class="button btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); editSurveyQuestion(question, $index)">
      {{app.translateByLocale('label_edit')}}
      </button>
      <button type="button" ng-if="question.type == allQuestionTypes.group" class="button btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); openModal(question, $index)">
      {{app.translateByLocale('label_edit')}}
      </button>
      <span class="delete-icon">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); removeGroup(question)">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 question-overview group-type-question-bar" ng-if="question.questions.length == 0">
      <div class="ellipsis text-center">
         <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
         <span>
         {{app.translateByLocale('group_questions_drag_info')}}
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div ng-repeat="subQuestion in question.questions" class="group-type-question">
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 question-overview" style="margin-left: 34px">
         <div class="ellipsis">
            <i class="fa fa-bars myHandle"></i>
            <!-- <input type="checkbox" ng-value="0" ng-model="subQuestion._selected" /> -->
            <span ng-attr-title="{{subQuestion.text}}">
            {{subQuestion.text}}
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 answer-overview pull-right word-wrap">
         <span class="badge">{{subQuestion.predefined_mcq_type.title}}</span>
         <span class="badge">{{showQuestionTypeText(subQuestion.type)}}</span>
         <button type="button" class="button btn btn-success btn-xs" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); editSurveyQuestion(subQuestion, $index)">
         {{app.translateByLocale('label_edit')}}
         </button>
         <span class="delete-icon">
         <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); removeSurveyGroupQuestion(subQuestion, question.questions)">
         <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
         </button>
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And These are Relavant Functions from Controller:

JS:

```
function sortableOptionsGroup(scope) {

    let sortableGroup = {
        handle: '.myHandle',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            sortingReceivedFunction(event, ui, scope);
        },
        remove: function(event, ui) {
            sortingRemovedFunction(event, ui, scope);
        },
        axis: 'y',
        'ui-floating': false,
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        connectWith: '.connector'
    }
    return sortableGroup;
}

/**
 * invoked when an item is added to the main group
 * 
 * @param {obj} event 
 * @param {obj} ui 
 * @param {obj} scope 
 * 
 * @returns none
 */
function sortingReceivedFunction(event, ui, scope) {
    let obj = ui.item.sortable.model;
    let index = ui.item.sortable.index;
    let group_type = null;
    let invalidIncomingQuestion = false;

    //Group Questions Types Maintaining
    // when second and more questions are added:
    if (ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel.length >= 1) {
        _.map(ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel, function(questionObject) {
            if (questionObject.type == allQuestionTypes.mcq && ui.item.sortable.model.type == allQuestionTypes.mcq && (questionObject.predefined_mcq_type.key != ui.item.sortable.model.predefined_mcq_type.key)) {
                invalidIncomingQuestion = true;
            }
        });
        if (invalidIncomingQuestion) {
            showErrorMessage(localeService.translateByLocale("group_question_error4"));
            cancelDraging(index, obj, scope, ui);
            return;
        } else if (ui.item.sortable.droptargetModel.length == maxQuestionLimitInGroup) {
            showErrorMessage(localeService.translateByLocale("group_question_error3"));
            cancelDraging(index, obj, scope, ui);
        } else if (incomingMcqQuestionValidation(ui.item.sortable.model)) {
            cancelDraging(index, obj, scope, ui);
        } else if (incomingCustomQuestionValidation(ui.item.sortable.model)) {
            cancelDraging(index, obj, scope, ui);
        } else {
            let groupQuestionId = ui.item.sortable.model.id;
            scope.questions.data.forEach(function(item, i, val) {
                if (scope.questions.data[i].id == groupQuestionId) {
                    scope.questions.data[i].isSelected = false;
                }
            });
        }

    }
    // when first question is added:
    else if (incomingMcqQuestionValidation(ui.item.sortable.model)) {
        cancelDraging(index, obj, scope, ui);
    } else if (incomingCustomQuestionValidation(ui.item.sortable.model)) {
        cancelDraging(index, obj, scope, ui);
    } else {
        let groupQuestionId = ui.item.sortable.model.id;
        scope.questions.data.forEach(function(item, i, val) {
            if (scope.questions.data[i].id == groupQuestionId) {
                scope.questions.data[i].isSelected = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
/**
 * invoked when an item is removed from the main group 
 * 
 * @param {obj} event 
 * @param {obj} ui 
 * @param {obj} scope 
 * 
 * @returns none
 */
function sortingRemovedFunction(event, ui, scope) {
    let groupQuestionId = ui.item.sortable.model.id;
    scope.questions.data.forEach(function(item, i, val) {
        if (scope.questions.data[i].id == groupQuestionId) {
            scope.questions.data[i].isSelected = true;
        }
    });
}
```

**Things are working pretty fine but there are few problems.**

1- When there are two adjacent groups and I try to drag an individual question into upper group, it always gets added into the lower/second group.
See in the image: I added `here is the text for question` in `group 1` but it added in `group 2`. Model of `group 1` is in console

[Groups after dragging a question in group 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSmjx.png)

2- I can't sort the questions within a group.

Can someone help me here on it. I've been trying quite hard on it.

Comment: have you found the answer ??? if so please add your answer, I am having same kind of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for the support by raising an issue in the GitHub repo and the solution which the owner suggested me was a bit messy. Ultimately I had to change the whole library in my code base. Here what I used..
https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Explore it. Hope it helps you too.